# Why am i getting black screen on Async task download exec in Android?

Tags: java, android

I'm getting a black screen when my async task execute. it takes 30-40 seconds until the app displays. till then there is a black screen, how can i solve it?
 I saw that the main methods that takes long, are the downloading objects from amazon S3, and unzipping.

```
//AsyncTasks 2
class secondAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Boolean> {
    Data newData = null;
    public String LOCAL_PATH = null;

    public secondAsyncTask(Data data) {
        newData = data;
        LOCAL_PATH = newData.context.getFilesDir().getPath().toString() ;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

    String fileName = newData.versionString + "_" + newData.timestampValue ;

    String KEY = fileName+ ".js" ;
    String KEY_ZIP = fileName + ".zip" ;
    String BUCKET_NAME = "galateajs" ;

    CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
            newData.context,
            "eu-west-1:3ad5de52-dfab-439f-96b1-8ebda", // Identity Pool ID
            Regions.EU_WEST_1 // Region
    );

    AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentialsProvider);

    File localFile = new File(LOCAL_PATH +"/dataFile.txt");
    File localFile_zip = new File(LOCAL_PATH +"/images.zip");

    //###
    // write to file
    try {
        ObjectMetadata object = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(BUCKET_NAME, KEY), localFile);

        try {
            newData.setPrefrence("timestamp", newData.timestampValue);//set new timestamp
            JSONObject objTmp = newData.readFromFile("dataFile.txt");// get new local file
            newData.updateJsonString(objTmp.toString());//update global var
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        newData.deleteImages(LOCAL_PATH + "/");
        newData.logFiles(LOCAL_PATH + "/");

        //download images
        ObjectMetadata object_zip = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(BUCKET_NAME, KEY_ZIP), localFile_zip);
        System.out.println("File Downloaded:    " + object_zip);
        newData.unpackZip(LOCAL_PATH + "/", "images.zip");

    } catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
        System.out.println("Error Message:    " + e.getMessage());
        System.out.println("HTTP Status Code: " + e.getStatusCode());
        System.out.println("AWS Error Code:   " + e.getErrorCode());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
    try {

        JSONObject objTmp = newData.readFromFile("dataFile.txt");
        newData.updateJsonString(objTmp.toString());

        Splash.notificationManager.cancel(Splash.notifyId);
        Toast.makeText(Splash.context,"Boat Saver data updated successfully!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
}
```

**How can i solve this?**

Comment: Show a progress bar in `onPreExecute` and stop it in `onPostExecute`

Comment: but i dont need a progress bar, i want that the user will be redirected to the app right away.

Comment: If you have long operation, you should implement Service.

Comment: Post the code that starts the `AsyncTask`